# Hidden field in acf

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I want to have a “like” field for every post, this field supposes to hold the number of likes for every post. But the problem is i don’t want it to be visible when editing post and no one except my code can change it. How can i do this with acf ?

Comment: The whole point of ACF is to have visible fields for editing the post. Why do you need ACF?

Answer (score 1):

Create a field group for just that field. In the Location panel under Rules, set **Show this field group if** to **Current User Role** *is equal to* **Administrator** - that way, your users won't see the field group but you still will (good for debugging).